# How to translate an raw SQL query to TypeORM query builder?

Tags: typeorm

How would I convert the subQuery select with distinct to TypeORM querybuilder? Thanks.

```
SELECT `time`, (case when `start` is NULL then 0 else 1 end) `is_reserved` FROM a left join (SELECT `time` FROM b join c on c.b_id = b.id WHERE b.date = '2022-04-20') MySchedule on MySchedule.time = a.time where a.is_use = 1

a table
time
is_use 

b table
id
date

c table
b_id
time
```